# The + adjective = replacing noun

Tags: legalese, nominal-adjectives

> **The Undersigned** certifies under oath that the information provided herein is true.

How far can you take the pattern where "the" plus an adjective replaces a noun?
Would this be more natural as long as the listener knows what nouns come after, than a complete phrase with a noun? Or are these more limited in usage and acceptance that people would only use this for words like "the poor" or "the rich", and a few more others which are already generalized?

Thank you.

Comment: Your example is specifically only used in legal situations (legal documents, etc)... It wouldn't be used regularly, if ever, outside of legal use... and "the undersigned" is actually a noun in this case, I would think... it literally means "The person who has signed the document somewhere below this point on the page".

Comment: The bereaved move solemnly up the aisle of the cathedral.  Also a noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done frequently in legal contexts, as Catija noted, but it can also occur in general contexts.

***The economically disadvantaged* have not had access to supermarkets selling fresh fruits and vegetables; the corporate food distribution chains have avoided those neighborhoods formerly known as "slums" or "the ghetto" and which today are called "the inner city".**

**In the US, it is customary for *the newly engaged* to send out so-called *Save The Date* announcements to their friends.**